# Specific MySQL PDO datetime insert [HY0093] error

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, pdo

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out what is wrong here and I am stumped.
Here's the specific PHP code that is failing:

```
//Handy function I use to do all my bound queries - yes you can have it.
function prepareBindAndExecute($pdo, $qry, $aParams) {
    if (!$stmt = $pdo->prepare($qry)) {
        setSessionError("Failed to prepare $qry");
        return false;
    }
    foreach ($aParams as $aParam) {
        // $aParam[0] = ":labelToBind"
        // $aParam[1] = value to Bind
        // $aParam[2] = PDO::PARAM_TYPE
        if (strpos($qry, $aParam[0]) !== false) {  // skip binding if label isn't in query.  This allows built up queries to not fail if parts were not created for a parameter.
            if (!$stmt->bindParam($aParam[0], $aParam[1], $aParam[2])) {
                setSessionError("Failed to bind $aParam[1] as $aParam[0] to $qry Error Info:".print_r($stmt->errorInfo()));
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        setSessionError("Failed to execute $qry bound with ".json_encode($aParams).' Error Info:'.print_r($stmt->errorInfo()));
        return false;
    }
    return $stmt;
}
// Here's the problem call: The member_login is a VARCHAR(32) receiving an email address string 
// and the submission_date is a DateTime column receiving the current date.
        $stmt = prepareBindAndExecute($pdoRW,
                                      'INSERT INTO videosubmissions (member_login, submission_date) VALUES (:login, :submission-date)',
                                      [ [ ':login',           $info['login'],   PDO::PARAM_STR ], 
                                        [ ':submission-date', $submission_date->format(DateTime::ISO8601), PDO::PARAM_STR ] ]);
```

Here's the results I get with this code:

> Failed to execute
>
> > INSERT INTO videosubmissions (member_login, submission_date) VALUES
> >     (:login, :submission-date)  bound with
> >     [[":login","xTst2@gmail.com",2],
> >     [":submission-date","2014-02-15T20:37:01+0100",2]]

With a related PHP error in the error log of:

> PHP Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: parameter was not defined in...

This simple case is NOT a mismatched number of parameters case as there are only two labels to bind.  My helper function has been working with much more complex queries than this one.
For awhile I thought I had this fixed by quoting the :label tag -> VALUES (":label", :submission_date...
This let the call succeed but resulted in the sting ":label" being inserted into the DB and would in fact, by my understanding, cause a true parameter count mismatch.
The PDO::PARAM_ constants do not offer a DATE or DATETIME flavor. (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php)
I have verified that my helper function did not skip binding any parameters - and we can seed this from the error message returned.

I have also tried binding the submission_date with a DateTime PHP object instead of a string and I have tried various data/time formated strings.
I am wondering if the @ in the login parameter is somehow screwing up the binding.
It would be nice if PDO would offer up what the actual query is that is being sent to the mySql but this might be buried in the driver.

Hopefully I am just missing something dumb.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Does using `bindValue` instead of `bindParam` fix it?

Comment: Try using `:submission_date` instead of `:submission-date`. Or `?` as placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno what's the problem with this particular code, but if to take out all the useless parts it can be boiled down to this, and I am pretty sure would work

```
function query($pdo, $qry, $aParams) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($qry);
    $stmt->execute($aParams);
    return $stmt;
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO videosubmissions (member_login, submission_date) VALUES (?, ?)';
query($pdoRW, $sql, [$info['login'], $submission_date->format(DateTime::ISO8601)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `-` in a placeholder name:

```
INSERT INTO [...snip...] (:login, :submission-date)',
                                            ^---
```

The `-` is not a valid char in a placeholder name, and MySQL will interpreter this as

```
 ... :submission MINUS date
```

Since you're not binding a value for `submission`, you get the invalid parameter number error. Even if you by-chance did have another placeholder whose name WAS `:submission`, you'd still end up with an SQL parser error due to the undefined/non-existent `date` field being used in what MySQL is seing as a subtraction operation.